Line cartoon, no real language, 60s-70s?
Okay, I have no idea about this one, I used to see it on SBS when I was a youngster because it was Italian in origin, and it's not on nowadays...
A fourth wall artist would draw a silhouette of a guy with a big nose. The silhouette would come to life and walk along (you could never see his feet when he was standing still). When the silhouette laughed it was rather annoying. The background was usually a loud color, and the line character was always silhouetted with a white outline.
The show would run in batches of 3-5 to fill a 15 minute time slot, and was often rather risque in nature although not obviously so...
Can anyone recall what this was called? I've been wracking my brains on this one...

Was this Italian? If so it could be La Linea, a popular cartoon running on RAI between 1971-1986.

Most episodes are available on Youtube.
Recently, the car manufacturer Ford payed homage to La Linea during their hybrid line launch, so it has re-entered the public consciousness.

Yes!!! This was it! The sheer minimalism of this series was brilliant!
Thanks buddy! I'd give you +2 if I could!

Haha, interesting to know. In Germany they used it for commercials for hemorrhoid ointment some years ago. Admittedly I never knew about this original.
